# Is there a way to render wide gamut colors (lch, lab etc.) directly through webGL?

Tags: webgl, color-space

Right now, I am rendering `lch` colors by converting them to `sRGB` and setting my fragment shader's `gl_FragColor` to the vector obtained from said conversion. This obviously does not render colors outside of `0-1` range correctly.

I was wondering if there was a way to create a fragment shader that can render the LCH colors directly. Any resources or a high level idea on how to go about this would be helpful.

Comment: What does it mean to render LCH colors directy? You can certainly render to an offscreen 4 channel texture and have those 4 channels represent LCH color but in order to display it you'd have to render that texture in the standard RGB of the canvas. The browser has no options for other color formats.

Comment: I meant if there was a way to "communicate" to browser that I want to render a color space other than sRGB. I realize now that that's not possible

Comment: It seems there was some proposal to support more than sRGB: https://github.com/WICG/canvas-color-space/blob/master/CanvasColorSpaceProposal.md But I don't see whether it went anywhere

Comment: You may be able to do it, but I think it will be very inefficient: you can find a way to attach a profile. One could do many complex transformation on newer ICC, but I doubt on good (and for sure not fast) support on browsers. I would try to solve the first problem.